# Value of type X cannot be converted to X. DLL Reference issue

Tags: windows, vb.net, dll, type-conversion, desktop

i have 2 solutions. Main solution (i.e solution 1) and framework solution(i.e solution 2).

Main solution has a project 'Utility' that is independant and is used in both solutions. I use Utility's dll in framework project references and in Main solution i am using Utility project direct reference. It was working fine for sometime. but now it is showing error in Main projects that value of type Utility cannot be converted to Utility.

Any idea? if this was occuring due to some code changes or reference issues?

Comment: Are you aware that you can add that Utility project to the other solution as well, rather than referencing a compiled DLL? You can right-click the solution and select Add -> Existing project and then select that project and it will appear as part of the solution. The project folder will still remain in only the original location and that path will be stored in the solution file.

Comment: Yes, in question i have clearified that in Main solution i am adding that Utility project to the other solution. but in framework i m using dll reference

Comment: My point was that you can add the same project to both solutions and not use a DLL reference at all. It's fine if you don't want to do that but many people don't even realise that you can.